# Why filter_var( true, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT ) returns 1

Tags: php

I can't understand why `filter_var(true, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)` returns 1

it should return **false** because true is not integer

Comment: How do you expect us to answer this without knowing what you're passing as `$variable`?

Comment: And why don't you use the built-in function `is_int` for this?

Comment: `filter_var(true, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)` returns `1`, not `TRUE`. [Fiddle](http://3v4l.org/5ujT9)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cause argument one is of type mixed so when you give a bool it cast it into int so it returns 1, you can test using var_dump

Comment: Based on your assumption `filter_var(false, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)` should return `0`, but it returns `false`. Your answer is incorrect at least for PHP 7.4.

Answer (score 1):

Try testing with `var_dump`...

```
var_dump(filter_var(true, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));
// this returns int(1)
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/U86x3r)**

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are not passing an integer.

Take a look at this:

```
var_dump(isInt(1)); // bool(true)
var_dump(isInt("1")); // bool(true)
var_dump(isInt("str")); // bool(false)
var_dump(isInt(array(1))); // bool(false)
```

Function is:

```
function isInt($variable){
if (filter_var( $variable, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT ) !== false) {
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```